# cakephp find returns empty array for spanish characters

Tags: cakephp, find, special-characters, cakephp-2.1

I am using the latest CakePHP (2.1.x) and when I do a find like the following, it returns an empty array when the `Model.name` field contains a Spanish character:

```
$this->Model->find(
        'list', 
        array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'LOWER(Model.name) LIKE' => '%'.$keyword.'%'
            ),
            'fields' => array(
                'Model.id', 
                'Model.name'
            )
        )
    );
```

When I display the `sql_dump` element, the query is just fine and it says 0 `Error`, 1 `Affected` and 1 `Num Rows`; plus when I try the query it's working just fine on the phpMyAdmin as well.

The whole website is in English and the content type is UTF-8. I tried to change the encoding without success.

The field is stored on the DB (MySQL) as `name varchar(255) latin1_swedish_ci` if this could be of any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you need to specify the utf-8 encoding on the database connection too

Check [this](http://www.missingfeatures.com/2008/10/23/using-utf8-in-your-cakephp-app/) out, hope it helps

Comment: Kudos to you, I just uncommented the `'encoding' => 'utf8',` line my DB connection and that did the trick! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to specify utf-8 for database:

Go to **ROOT/app/config/database.php**

In class DATABASE_CONFIG change **encoding**

```
'encoding' => 'utf8',
```